Just need a bit of help for my search bar
I have copied an youtube tutorial of how to make an "autocomplete search bar" - Made By GreekStack, Everything is working fine I was just wondering if there was an way to actually redirect the user to an different HTML page.
I would like to make my search bar be able to redirect users to an different HTML page. This is made with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS.


let avaliableKeywords = [
  '6TEST6',
  '5TEST5',
  '4TEST4',
  '3TEST3',
  '2TEST2',
  '1TEST1',
];

const resultsBox = document.querySelector(".result-box")
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box")

inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  let result = [];
  let input = inputBox.value;
  if (input.length) {
    result = avaliableKeywords.filter((keyword) => {
      return keyword.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase());
    });
    console.log(result);
  }
  display(result);

  if (!result.length) {
    resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

function display(result) {
  const content = result.map((list) => {
    return "<li onclick=selectInput(this)>" + list + "</li>";
  });

  resultsBox.innerHTML = "<ul>" + content.join('') + "</ul>";
}


function selectInput(list) {
  inputBox.value = list.innerHTML
  resultsBox.innerHTML = '';
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins" sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #181818
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  width: 600px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
}

.row-search {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

input {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #333;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

button .Srch-img {
  width: 25px;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: #555;
}

.result-box ul {
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.result-box ul li {
  list-style: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result-box ul li:hover {
  background: #e9f3ff;
}

.result-box {
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/dist/boxicons.js"></script>

<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">FYE-Movies</a>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="Movies.html">Featured Movies</a>
    <a href="Series.html">Series</a>
    <a href="Search.html">Search</a>
    <a href="Beta.html">BETA Version</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="search-box">
    <div class="row-search">
      <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Search Movies" autocomplete="off">
      <button><img class="Srch-img" src="data:image/png;base64,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"/></button>
    </div>
    <div class="result-box">
    </div>
  </div>




Is your search bar currently in a form? You should [edit] your question to include all relevant code as a [mre].

What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  Are you just asking how to perform a redirect in JavaScript?

Just added my html and css

your <style< section should be in the  section

okay I did that, but how do I make it redirect them?

the  tag is not closed in the snippet

Your button currently does nothing; seems like you'd need to add an event listener to it and use document.location.href to send them to the other page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage

Okay, I have closed the header.

let me see, ill get back to you.

I'm a bit confused, I would like each "Test" to go to an different link. It should all work in VS if you would like to test it out. I'm not very good at js.

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Wrap in a form and change location on submit
const searchForm = document.getElementById("searchForm")
const inputBox = document.getElementById("input-box")

searchForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  // e.target.action = `https://google.com/search?q=${inputBox.value}`;
  e.preventDefault();
  location = `https://test.com/${inputBox.value}.html`;
})

<div class="search-box">
  <form id="searchForm" target="_blank">
    <div class="row-search">
      <input type="text" id="input-box" placeholder="Search Movies" autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit">...</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>


does not seem to be working.

The list is not showing

Copy it to your server  and run it from there

Try now. Your CSS had moved the search box too far to the left

I have just noticed an problem, when I try to load the page on my paid domain it does not seem to be showing anything.

And the console has no errors.

Okay I fixed it, Thank you. But the files do not seem to be updating to my ftp account, I add them, and they do not update to my domain.

Sorry, I cannot help with that

Okay, how do I remove the "?" from the end of the link
ex: "https://somthing.com/Somthing.html?"

I do not understand what you mean. If you do not put it there it will not be there.
If you want to redirect to   e.target.action = \https://something.com/something.html` then do that. If you want to pass the value to it, then you need the ?:`https://something.com/something.html?${value}` `

e.target.action = https://test.com/${inputBox.value}.html
This is an example of my code, it redirects me to https://TEST.com/${inputBox.value}.html?

Ok - sounds like a server issue. Try changing it to e.preventDefault(); location = \https://test.com/${inputBox.value}.html`;`

I took an break off of my computer to spend some time with my family, But it works, Thank You.
